# How to solve the equation $ (x-2)^{\log_{100}(x-2)}+\log_{10}(x-2)^5-12 = 10^{2\log_{10}(x-2)}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms, roots

> If $\displaystyle (x-2)^{\log_{10^2}(x-2)}+\log_{10}(x-2)^5-12 = 10^{2.\log_{10}(x-2)}$, then value of $x$ is ...

#### My Try

Let$$\log_{10}(x-2) = y \quad \Leftrightarrow \quad (x-2)=10^y .$$

Then$$(10)^{(y) (\frac{1}{2})(y)}+5y-12=10^{2y} .$$

Now, how can I calculate the value of $y$?

Thanks.

Comment: Looking to the exponents, $4$ is a decent estimation for a solution. But [I don't think it has a closed form](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%2810%29%5E%7By*y%2F2%7D%2B5y-12%3D10%5E%7B2y%7D)

Comment: Please introduce $y=x-2$ as a first step :)

Comment: The reason the solution is so close to $y=4$ is that $y=4$ satisfies $10^\frac{y^2}2=10^{2y}$ and a slight change in the equation, like a line which grows much more slowly than the exponentials, makes the solution be slightly off from $y=4$

Answer (score 1):

$$f(y)=10^{\frac{y^2}{2}}+5 y-100^y-12 \quad \implies \quad f(4)=8$$

Let $y=(4-t)$ and consider
$$g(t)=-5 t-10^{8-2 t}+10^{\frac{1}{2} (t-4)^2}+8$$
$$g'(t)=10^{\frac{1}{2} (t-4)^2} (t-4) \log (10)+2^{9-2 t} 5^{8-2 t} \log(10)-5$$
Expand as a series around $t=0$
$$g(t)=8-t (5+200000000 \log (10))+O\left(t^2\right)$$ So, our first estimate is
$$t_0=\frac{8}{5 (1+40000000 \log (10))}$$
$$g(t_0)\times g''(t_0)\sim 6188.89$$ So, by Darboux theorem, we already know that the convergence will be obtained without any overshoot.

Now, use
$$t_{n+1}=t_n-\frac {g(t_n)} {g'(t_n)}$$

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
n & t_n \times 10^8 \\
 0 & 1.7371779087518378142256686166520518855449483730878 \\
 1 & 1.7371781247576895120499294046957378804329785915514 \\
 2 & 1.7371781247576895120532691080810907240450255801509 \\
 3 & 1.7371781247576895120532691080810907240450255801517 \\
 4 & 1.7371781247576895120532691080810907240450255801517 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$